# Stopping a service from a socket

Tags: systemd

I'm having problems stopping a service remotely.

I've got a simple socket/service pair:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/foo.socket
[Unit]
Description=The socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=11111
```

```
# /etc/systemd/system/foo.service
[Unit]
Description=The service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=sleep infinity
```

After `systemctl start foo.socket` it looks like:

```
foo.socket:  active (listening)
foo.service: inactive (dead)
```

Then establishing a connection from another machine with `netcat 10.10.1.16 11111`, we get:

```
foo.socket:  active (running)
foo.service: active (running)
```

Perfect!

Now if we kill the connection (`SIGTERM` to `netcat`), we get:

```
foo.socket:  active (running)
foo.service: active (running)
```

But I expected:

```
foo.socket:  active (listening)
foo.service: inactive (dead)
```

How can I use the TCP connection to stop the service remotely?

I've tried:

- `Accept=yes` with `foo@.service`
- Making the service `PartOf=foo.socket` or `Requires=foo.socket`
- `StandardInput=socket` along with stdout and stderr.

Comment: Which do you want to stop, the service or the socket?  You say one in one place and the other in another.

Comment: I want to stop the service.  Socket is fine to return to the "listening" state.  Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `/bin/sleep infinity` you want to run something different:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=foo
StandardInput=socket
```

Where `foo` is any of:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int, char**) {
  char buf[256];
  while(scanf("%255s",buf) > 0) {}
  return 0;
}
```

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line; do
  echo "$line"
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    pass
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
  if (eof()) { exit }
}
```

---

### Explanation:

When you use a `Type=simple` service, the service will stop as soon as the `ExecStart` process ends.  So even if you close the connection, the service doesn't stop because the application doesn't know it should quit.  Systemd won't send SIGTERM and it doesn't need to.

Instead, I've provided four implemenatations (C, sh, python, perl) of an `ExecStart` process which do the same thing:  read from stdin until stdin isn't available anymore.  When your connection is closed, the stream ends, which means stdin ends.  So just keep reading stdin until you get EOF, then quit.  As soon as your process quits, the service will stop.

---

### Built in functions

If you don't want to deploy one of the above scripts, use one of the builtin tools which listen to stdin and quit on EOF.  The side-effect is that they may actually do something.  The first I can think of is `grep -`.  It returns `EXIT_FAILURE` if it doesn't match anything so prefix it with `-` to ensure you don't end up with a failed service every time you close a connection.

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=-/bin/grep -
StandardInput=socket
```

If you think taking advantage of this process could be fun, then maybe make your connection possibly do something useful.  The second program I can think of is `python3`. So now you can have an entire interpreter just sitting idle on standby waiting to do something for you.  This can be dangerous if you don't add some sandboxing, but systemd can do that for us with `DynamicUser=`.

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3
StandardInput=socket
DynamicUser=yes
```

If you want some confirmation on the client-side that connections are established, perhaps consider using `cat`. First create some boilerplate text:

```
echo "established" > /usr/local/etc/simple/start_text
```

Then tell systemd to cat that text, followed by stdin

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=-cat /usr/local/etc/simple/start_text -
StandardInput=socket
```

Now `netcat` on your client will get a printout when the connection is established.

It's also worth noting that you should use `Accept=yes` and `foo@.service`.  Otherwise, systemd will expect that your application can accept incoming connections, which is not the case here.